# Getting the results of an Array.toString() without having the items separated by a comma

Tags: javascript, string, tostring

I have an array with messages on them, some of which contain commas. I would like to make this whole array into a string by using `.toString()`, but instead of separating them by commas, I'd like to separate them by line breakers (`\n`).

Unfortunately, since some of these messages are long and may contain commas of their own, I don't think simply replacing them all using `myArray.replace(/,/g, '\n')` will do the trick.

I know I could also simply do a `.forEach()` and copy the strings into a new big string. But I was wondering if there is a better way to do this? Perhaps somehow overload the `toString()` method so that the items are separated by `\n` instead of the comma?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `join('\n')` for that case. `Array.join()` allows you to specify the combiner between the array elements. `\n` in this case. Similarly, you can use any character or text for the combiner between the array elements like `join(',')`, `join('-')` or any other. `join(',')` is same as `toString()`

```js
var arr = ['some', 'word', 'here'];
var res = arr.join('\n');
console.log(res);
```

Comment: In fact, [`toString` *calls* `join`](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-array.prototype.tostring). :-) It doesn't provide any argument, so `join` uses its default `","`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder agree with you.

Comment: :-) It's not really a matter of opinion.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder that's good to know! I'll be using mainly `join` now